# How to download a file protected by Cloudflare in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, cloudflare

I'm using Android WebView to download files from the URL entered by the user (including protected by Cloudflare), it looks something like this:

```
 private final DownloadListener downloadListener = new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url,
                                    String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition,
                                    String mimeType,
                                    long contentLength)
        {
            while (redirectionCount++ < MAX_REDIRECTS) {
                HttpURLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(...);
                conn.setReadTimeout(...);
                conn.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(context));
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
                // Get the cookies for the current URL.
                String cookiesString = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookiesString);

                ...
            } 
        }
    };
```

I get the url from the WebView's `DownloadListener`, open the connection and pass the cookies obtained from WebView to the request header (`cf_clearance=***; cf_chl_2=***; cf_chl_prog=***; cf_chl_rc_ni=***`) and also WebView user-agent. JS and cookies are enabled in the WebView.

But the problem is that `HttpURLConnection` keeps returning HTTP 503 even if I pass the Cloudflare cookies, although the WebView seems to pass the Cloudflare checking. Maybe it requires something other than the cookies themselves?

Comment: Are you able to access this URL directly in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I can download this URL in the regular browser, but I can't in the WebView + HttpUrlConnection. It just returns HTTP 503 infinitely, although the WebView seems to pass the Cloudflare checking.

Comment: I'm not certain how to solve this. One thing I would look at is if there are any headers you need to add to the request, such as `Authorization`.

Comment: I studied the requests that the browser sends and did not find such headers there. I've even tried copying the entire request and submitting it, and it doesn't work. It seems that Cloudflare uses JS to determine some browser metrics to identify it